# windows form datagridview, giving IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, datagridview, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a datagridview 6x6 made out of randomly generated numbers and I want to read every cell in the datagrid and check how many numbers are duplicates, I thought a good idea would be to get every cells value into an array and sort it. once it was sorted I would check every value and the one next to it and see if they were the same and if they were I would increase the counter.My problem is when I run this code I get a `System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'` on the part where we iterate over the datagridview, this line "`numeros[c] = Convert.ToInt16(cell.Value);`".
After some testing i tried to just show every cell value and they appeared as 0.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int cont = 0;
            int[] numeros = new int[36];
            int c = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    numeros[c] = Convert.ToInt16(cell.Value);
                    c++;
                }
            }
            Array.Sort(numeros);
            label12.Text = "";
            for(int i = 0; i < 36; i++)
            {
                label12.Text += numeros[i].ToString() + ", ";
                if (i == 35)
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (numeros[i] == numeros[i + 1])
                    {
                        cont++;
                    }
                }

            }
            label7.Text = cont.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: does that mean that Rows returns all the column including the header?

Comment: Looks like your grid is greater than 6x6. Please check exact Rows and Columns count in debugger

Comment: you are correct the grid appears 7x7 but i don't know why it only has 6 columns and 6 rows

Comment: i just noticed that it has an empty row in the bottom of the grid, how do i get rid of it?

Comment: See grid properties in VS, there should be option to remove empty row at the bottom. It's used to let user append new rows. Try to set grid read only / disable editing.

Comment: with some quick research i found the solution thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the grid had an extra blank row at the bottom that had to be removed and the program worked fine